# NoSuchElementException on scanner

Tags: nosuchelementexception

**EDIT: I've found the exception to occour on line 24: "choice = scanner.nextInt();" But why, IDK**

Why do I get a "NoSuchElementException" when using my scanner in the switch to get case 4 and choosing 4 teams in the "viewTournaments" method?

Please ignore the try/catch blocks around the switch (it was an attempt to properbly close all scanners).

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        while (!quit) {

            choice = scanner.nextInt();

            if (choice > 5 || choice < 0) {
                System.out.println("Wrong input. Please input a number between 1 and 4: ");
                choice = scanner.nextInt();
            }

            switch (choice) {
                case 0:
                    instructions();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    viewCoaches(url, username, password);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewPeople(url, username, password);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewTeams(url, username, password);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    viewTournaments(url, username, password);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Thank you for using our database! \nBye for now");
                    System.out.println("Terminating program safely. Please wait...");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        quit = true;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(CSManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Calling the method from case 4:

```
public static void viewTournaments(String url, String username, String password) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the amount of teams for the tournament: \n");
        int i = scan.nextInt();

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String sql
                = "SELECT tournaments.tournamentname, COUNT(participates.tournament_id) "
                + "FROM participates "
                + "INNER JOIN tournaments ON tournaments.tournament_id = participates.tournament_id "
                + "GROUP BY tournaments.tournamentname "
                + "HAVING COUNT(participates.tournament_id) >= " + i;
        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (result.next()) {
            String tournamentname = result.getString("tournamentname");
            String numbOfTeams = result.getString("count");
            System.out.println("Tournament: " + tournamentname + "\tNumber of participating teams: " + numbOfTeams);
        }
        result.close();
        st.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the right data in the console but when it's done it sends me this exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at csmanager.CSManager.main(CSManager.java:24)
```

Line 24 is the one with "choice = scanner.nextInt();"

Sorry for the code-bomb :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner not asking for input , throws No Such Element Exception - multiple scanners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620428/scanner-not-asking-for-input-throws-no-such-element-exception-multiple-scann)

Answer (score 0):

[ANSWER] For some wierd reason was it a prolbem for Java that the Scanner in the viewTournaments being closed after the block has been treated. By making sure that the scanner in viewTournaments is not autocloseable (in the try-with-resources) and keeping it open for the duration of the runtime the exception will not appear.
Why this fixes it, I hornestly don't know.