# Scanner not asking for input , throws No Such Element Exception - multiple scanners

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

In the below code I have used two scanners, One in performAction() method and one in getTicketNumber() method. I have used try with resources and once when I go into getTicketNumber() method, it works fine and once when the control returns back and comes to performAction() I am getting No Such Element Exception when it executes the scanner.nextInt() line. I wanted to continue this process until I press exit. I guess it is due to the use of multiple scanners since if I don't go into getTicketNumber() method, it works fine. Any ideas?

```
private void performAction() {
    int choice = 4;
    System.out.println("Hi User");
    System.out.println("What do you want to do ");
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        do {
            System.out.println("1. Book ticket");
            System.out.println("2. Cancel ticket");
            System.out.println("3. Check status");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");
            System.out.println("Enter your choice");
            choice = scanner.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
            doActionBasedOnChoice(choice);
            System.out.println();
        } while (choice != 4);

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice");
    }
}

private void doActionBasedOnChoice(int choice) {

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        ticketReservation.bookFlight();
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Please enter your ticket number ");
        int ticketNumber = getTicketNumber();
        ticketReservation.cancel(ticketNumber);
        break;
    case 3:
        ticketReservation.checkConfirmedListStatus();
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Thank you ");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

private int getTicketNumber() {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        return choice;
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid ticekt number");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the "inner" scanner passes out of scope, it is disposed by the try-block, which in turn closes the System.in stream.

Solve by passing the scanner along to whoever needs it, or alternatively move it to a higher scope.

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out that when you use try with resource it will close the resource automatically, and once the `System.in` is closed it cannot be reopened.
So Suggestion is use one Scanner Object and pass it via args to different methods

Comment: You do not want to close `System.in` - you can not reopen it.

Comment: But passing resource as method parameters as I learnt is not actually a good practice.Since , I am using try with resources it will automatically close the resource once it comes out of the try with resouces block since Scanner implements autoclosable interface. I had even tried using scanner.close() in the getTicketNumber() method but even that dosen't seem to work ! Any ideas ? Thanks !